# the iframe is not working what shall i do

Tags: html

```html
<iframe width="640" height="390" src="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=rf-ZbfUTVO0" ></iframe>
```

i did like this but is is not working. I tried this many time but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to embed any youtube video then you can click on the share button of Youtube, there you'll find the embed code just like below. I did this and it's working for me.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rf-ZbfUTVO0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . I was stuck there for a lot of time